# How to send emails for each person in a excel file

Tags: python, pandas, email, path, smtplib

So i have a file em.xlsx where i have Name & Email columns, i want to send email when Name matchs the the filename in a directory

How can i do that ? so far i have this code below, but it actualy return nothing

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import os
from collections import ChainMap
# Spreadsheet with emails and  names
email_list = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\arabw\OneDrive\Bureau\html\em.xlsx')
folder_path= "C:/Users/arabw/OneDrive/Bureau/html/"
my_files=[{each_file.split(".")[0]:each_file} for each_file in os.listdir(folder_path) if each_file.endswith(".csv")]
my_files_dict = dict(ChainMap(*my_files))
# getting the names and the emails
names = email_list['Name']
emails = email_list['Email']
 
for i in range(len(emails)): # iterate through the records
    # for every record get the name and the email addresses
    name = names[i]
    email = emails[i]
    if my_files_dict.get(name):
        print(f"file found:{my_files_dict.get(name)}") # attach this file : my_files_dict.get(name)
    #Some  help needed from here I believe
    while name == os.path:
         smtp_ssl_host = 'xxxxx'
         smtp_ssl_port = 465
         email_from = "xxxxx"
         email_pass = "xxxxx"
         email_to = email
         msg2 = MIMEMultipart()
         msg2['Subject'] = "Present Record(s)"
         msg2['From'] = email_from
         msg2['To'] = email
         fo=open(my_files_dict.get(name),'rb')
         attach = email.mime.application.MIMEApplication(fo.read(),_subtype="xlsx")
         fo.close()
         attach.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',my_files_dict.get(name))
         msg.attach(attach)
         s2 = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
         s2.login(email_from, email_pass)  
         s2.send_message(msg)
         s2.quit()
```

Comment: So files1 isn't been used, right?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do: `while name == os.path:`

Comment: xpie yes, gimix if the name in the file is found it action the while loop ? but idk if its the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code passed my test. Hope it can help you. I'm not sure what's `while name == os.path:` for, so I just ignore it.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
import email
import os
from collections import ChainMap
# Spreadsheet with emails and  names
email_list = pd.read_excel('email.xlsx')
folder_path= './Files/A'
my_files=[{each_file.split(".")[0]:each_file} for each_file in os.listdir(folder_path) if each_file.endswith(".csv")]
my_files_dict = dict(ChainMap(*my_files))
# getting the names and the emails
names = email_list['Name']
emails = email_list['Email']

for i in range(len(emails)): # iterate through the records
    # for every record get the name and the email addresses
    name = names[i]
    email_item = emails[i]
    file_name = my_files_dict.get(name)
    if file_name:
        print(f"file found:{file_name}") # attach this file : my_files_dict.get(name)
    #Some  help needed from here I believe
        # while name == os.path:
        smtp_ssl_host = 'smtp.xxx.com'
        smtp_ssl_port = 465
        email_from = "xxxxx"
        email_pass = "xxxxx"
        email_to = email_item
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['Subject'] = "Present Record(s)"
        msg['From'] = email_from
        msg['To'] = email_item
        fo=open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), 'rb')
        attach = MIMEApplication(fo.read(), _subtype="xlsx")
        fo.close()
        attach.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_name)
        msg.attach(attach)
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_ssl_host, smtp_ssl_port)
        try:
            smtp.login(email_from, email_pass)
            smtp.sendmail(email_from, email_to, msg.as_string())
        except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
            print("send fail", e)
        else:
            print("success")
        finally:
            try:
                smtp.quit()
            except smtplib.SMTPException:
                print("quit fail")
            else:
                print("quit success")
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response, i tried to execute the code, but i actually get this type of error  
`File "c:\Users\arabw\OneDrive\Bureau\html\test.py", line 37, in <module>
    fo=open(os.path.join(folder_path, my_files_dict.get(name)), 'rb')
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'NoneType'`

Comment: What about now? Maybe you can check the value of ```folder_path``` and ```file_name```.

Comment: the value of folderpath  `./fichiers`       (here are stored my excel files)
and the value of file_name returned is  `None`

Comment: ok so my files end with xlsx, and in the code it is csv, that's why `each_file.endswith(".csv")]`  ,it works fine actually thank you ! :)

Comment: My pleasure. But I can't understand where file_name can be None. There is an ```if file_name:```, why file_name is None but in the ```if```.